# Imprimir Modal com estilo CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando imprimir um modal com estilo css usando a função abaixo:

**Conteúdo do modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="infoModal">

   <!--Aqui vai o conteúdo do modal-->

   <div class="row no-print"><!-- Botão que chama a função -->

       <div class="col-12">

          <a onClick="imprimeModal()" target="_blank" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Imprimir</a>
                                             
       </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Função:**

```
function imprimeModal(){

        var conteudo = document.getElementById('infoModal').innerHTML,
        tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');
        tela_impressao.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');
        tela_impressao.document.write('<html lang="pt-br">');
        tela_impressao.document.write('<head><title>Teste</title>');        
        tela_impressao.document.write('<link href="../css/print.css" rel="stylesheet">');  
        tela_impressao.document.write('</head><body>');    
        tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
        tela_impressao.document.write('</body>');
        tela_impressao.window.print();
        tela_impressao.window.close();

    }
```

Quando eu clico no botão imprimir a primeira vez gera o arquivo **sem estilo CSS**, mas quando eu clico uma segunda vez ele gera o arquivo **com estilo CSS**. Se eu fecho o modal e abro de novo acontece a mesma coisa... Alguém sabe me dizer se estou fazendo algo de errado?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode estar utilizando a solução abaixo, você consegue realizar a impressão sem perder o CSS.
Se o site for para acesso via mobile remove a seguinte linha do script.
// Remover div uma vez impresso
$print.remove();

```js
function imprimir(selector) {
  var $print = $(selector)
    .clone()
    .addClass('print')
    .prependTo('body');

  // Pausa JS executado
  window.print();

  // Remover div uma vez impresso
  $print.remove();
}
```

```css
  @media print and (color) {
    @page {
      margin: 5mm;
      size: A4 portrait;
    }

    * {
      overflow: visible !important;
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
      print-color-adjust: exact !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      color: #212121 !important;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nomeModal">


</div>                


<button type="button" onClick="imprimir(nomeModal)">
                 Imprimir
                </button>
```